# .NET Process fails on Windows 8

Tags: c#, process, windows-8

I have two weird problems running an app on Windows 8 (which works fine on Windows 7)

I'm running external "a.exe" app.

First issue is that when I run "a.exe" using Process - I don't get any output. 
If I run a batch file which executes "a.exe" and write output to a file - there is an output.

The second issue is that in both cases (Batch and Process) "a.exe" fails. But from command line it works.

Here is the code:

```
 proc = new Process();
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path;
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
 proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = GetDirectoryName(Path); 
 proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;                
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas administrator";

 proc.OutputDataReceived += (sendingProcess, line) =>
 {
    string s = line.Data;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
      _sbStdout.AppendLine(line.Data);
    }
 };


 proc.ErrorDataReceived += (sendingProcess, line) =>
 {
    string s = line.Data;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
       _sbStderr.AppendLine(line.Data);
    }
 };    

 proc.Start();

 proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
 proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

// Wait for exit or timeout   
bool res = true;

if (timeout <= 0 || timeout == null)
   proc.WaitForExit(); 
else
   res = proc.WaitForExit((int)timeout);

ExitCode = proc.ExitCode;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: This is not the right place to report Windows 8 bugs.  The current version is just a preview, not a beta, so there is no formal way yet to report bugs.  You'll find hints on using the Windows Feedback tool here: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/install-windows-8-feedback-tool-submit-bugs-windows-8-developer-preview

Comment: What is the value of args and Path?